# Accessing one service for two different application

Tags: c#, wcf

i have create a web application.i want to access that service from another application in my local .. can some one help me how to configure my local IIs server so that both the application access the same service .Thanks in advance .. my local web application service am calling like this .THanks in advance

http://localhost:XXXX/drop.svc/Temp/id

Comment: This is very basic question, did you google it ?

Comment: Yo can read [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx) and [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx) and [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675150(v=vs.110).aspx) articles to know how you can host services on IIS.

Comment: @Aria thanks let me check on this